# IllegalStateException: zip file closed during file write

Tags: java, jar, classloader

This bug occurs when my program enters the shutdown hook and tries to write the settings file to a text document.  The strange thing is, it doesnt throw an exception everytime.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.crimson.server.JarClassLoader.findJarEntry(JarClassLoader.java:514)
    at com.crimson.server.JarClassLoader.findJarClass(JarClassLoader.java:584)
    at com.crimson.server.JarClassLoader.loadClass(JarClassLoader.java:956)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.crimson.universalUtils.Datastore.store(Datastore.java:66)
    at com.crimson.server.ServerShutdownHook.run(ServerShutdownHook.java:38)
```

Here is Datastore.store(Settings):

```
public static File set = new File("settings.properties");

public static void store(Settings settings){
    set.delete();

    try {
        set.createNewFile();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(set);//line 66
        pw.println(ObjectTransfer.toString(settings));

        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I dont know why creating the PrintWriter calls ClassLoader.loadClass, but that could be the problem because im using JarClassLoader: http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php

Comment: Is the code getting called from multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the [source code](http://www.jdotsoft.com/download/JarClassLoader.java) of `JarClassLoader` and the problem is that JarClassLoader also has a shutdown hook to close the jar file. And as the [documentation of shutdown hooks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) says, they may be invoked in any order, or even in parallel. So when your hook "gets in" before `JarClassLoader`s, your code works. When it's a bit too late, you get this exception.

A way to get around this would be to ensure the `PrintWriter` class is loaded before invoking the shutdown hook.

Comment: That was exactly it. I dont know if you could help with this secondary question as well, but I havent been able to find a good method to selectively load jars using JarClassLoader; it loads them all. Would you happen to have any insight on that?

Comment: @user3109490 You can force the loading of the `PrintWriter` class by instantiating it in code that runs before the shutdown hook. But instead of this trickery I'd probably just switch to a different solution, like [OneJar](https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/).